# Не могу подключиться к виртуальной машине Yandex Cloud

Tags: yandex-cloud

У меня в windows 10 стоит ssh, версия: unknown пишет, конфигурационного файла нет. Есть только публичный ключ, логин, имя ВМ, публичный IP. Я просто добавил публичный ключ в file.pub. После запустил :

```
ssh -i path/file.pub vm_name@IP
```

и получил ошибки:

```
vm_name@IP: Permission Denied (publickey)
```

Что мне делать? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Подключаться нужно с использование приватного ключа, а не публичного. Вероятно так: `ssh -i path/file vm_name@IP`

Comment: А для чего тогда мне был выслан публичный?

Comment: Публичный вы указываете при создании виртуальной машины в облаке. Публичный хранится на ВМ, а приватный — у вас.

Comment: А что делать если не указали публичный ключ при создании?

Comment: Ну, я попробовал приватный ключ и он пишет, что invalid format, а в файле кроме одной длинной строки приватного ключа нет ничего..